# Интерпретации предложений с наречием редко

Tags: синтаксис

Какое предложение (какие предложения) допускают более одной интерпретации, связанной с наречием *редко* и почему?

1. Дипломаты редко дают однозначные ответы.
2. Волки редко поддаются приручению.
3. В средние века люди редко доживали до старости.
4. Садовые лестницы редко имеют декоративное предназначение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Редкий — тот, кто принадлежит к числу немногих; 
1) а) Состоящий из далеко друг от друга расположенных однородных единиц или частиц; не частый, не густой. 
2) Следующий один за другим через какие-л. промежутки.
 3) а) Не часто или мало встречающийся; не обычный

Подбираем синонимы к словам и сравниваем их между собой.

1)  Дипломаты редко ( не всегда, не часто) дают однозначные ответы (имеется в виду:  чаше дают неоднозначные ответы (с подтекстом))
2)  Дипломаты редко ( не всегда, не часто) дают однозначные ответы
(имеется в виду:  всё же дают их – эти ответы)
•   Волки редко (не часто) поддаются приручению.
•   В средние века люди редко (не часто) доживали до старости.
•   Садовые лестницы редко (не часто) имеют декоративное предназначение.